# Apply XSLT in a AJAX request

Tags: xml, ajax, xslt, styles

I have a HTML page which loads via AJAX a piece of XML.
Is there a way to apply XSLT (preferably on the client side) to this piece of XML to style it?

Comment: Superb question. Good self-answer too.

Answer (score 1):

upon further research:
http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/   (this one I currently work with)
http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/
etc...